# How do i get the direction or the position that the character of the Player is looking?

Tags: lua, roblox, luau

I have a question that I've been wanting to know the answer to for a while. How to get the position and direction the player character is looking? I want to know this because I need to make a system that involves this.

Comment: Are you asking about where the camera is looking? Or where the character model is facing?

Comment: The character model is facing

Comment: See the [LookVector property on CFrames](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/CFrame#properties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in ROBLOX, all `BaseParts` have a property named `CFrame` which represents the Position and Orientation of that `BasePart`.

Now if you wanna find the where the character is looking, we could check the direction the character's `Head` is facing by utilizing its `CFrame`. (*since we can't get the `CFrame` of a model*). To do this, we can reference the character `Head` and then get the `LookVector` property of its `CFrame`. And voila you got the direction where the character is facing. But there is a slight issue, you see-`LookVector` is not a *positional* vector but rather a *directional* vector, as such it will have a `Magnitude` (length) of 1. So if we want to find the position the character is looking at, we need to multiply this `LookVector` by a number which will denote the number of studs in the direction of the character we want to look and then add it with the position of the `Head`.

So based on the above, you can do this:

```
local Head: BasePart = LocalPlayer.Character.Head.CFrame

local Direction: Vector3 = Head.LookVector
local Distance: number = 3 -- Look 3 studs in the direction of the `Head`

local Target: Vector3 = Head.Position + (Direction * Distance)
```